# How to run selenium standalone behind a proxy?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-grid

Several days ago I bumped into a need of using Selenium `webdriver.Remote` with proxy auth.
I found few articles that enlighten this topic just a bit.
So I would like to share my **solution**. I hope someone might well find it usefull.

Python 3.10.11

Package requirements:
selenium==4.9.0 # On futher versions of Selenium it won't work due to API changes
selenium-wire==5.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from seleniumwire import webdriver


PROXY_USERNAME = "USERNAME"
PROXY_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
CURRENT_MACHINE_IP = "YOUR_CURRENT_MACHINE_IP"
BACKEND_PORT = 8087  # any awailable port

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={CURRENT_MACHINE_IP}:{BACKEND_PORT}")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

seleniumwire_options = {
    "addr": CURRENT_MACHINE_IP,
    "auto_config": False,
    "proxy": {
        "http": f"http://{PROXY_USERNAME}:{PROXY_PASSWORD}@PROXY_LINK:PROXY_PORT",
        "https": f"http://{PROXY_USERNAME}:{PROXY_PASSWORD}@PROXY_LINK:PROXY_PORT",
        "no_proxy": "localhost,127.0.0.1",
        "verify_ssl": False,
    },
    "port": BACKEND_PORT,
}

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor="http://127.0.0.1:4444",
    desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities(),
    seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options,
)

try:
    driver.get("https://python.org/")
    with open("test.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(driver.page_source)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
  services:
    selenium:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
      environment:
        - SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=30
        - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=5
        - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      ports:
        - 4444:4444
```